# Is a 350VDC capacitor safe for rectified 240VAC?

Tags: capacitor, mains, safety

I need some capacitors to smooth out rectified mains (long story short, I see 50 Hz light flickering, so I need lights running on DC instead). While looking, I saw that 350V capacitors cost me only a third as much as the 400V capacitors I have been using so far.

Mains in my country is 240 V, which means peak voltage of 339 V, which leaves 11 V margin, however, that doesn't include potential voltage spikes I might encounter. Are these capacitors safe to use or should I stick with the 400 V just to be sure?

Edit: Please stop saying you need to know what lights I'm using, it is not that important. I know the lights I am using will work as I have done it before, this is simply about doing it slightly cheaper in the future.

Comment: What kind of lights are you referring to here? LED? Fluorescent? Incandescent? Depending on which they are, rectifying and smoothing the mains could: have no effect, or it could make them run hotter & brighter and fail much sooner, or it could make them simply not work at all.

Comment: Unfortunately we do not have any idea of what else is specified for your 350V capacitors. We do not know do they stay alive in your application because 1) nobody here knows how much AC current you are going to put through them as charging and discharging and 2) what continuous AC current they are rated for. Also your top voltage marginal is minimal. It can well be too small one day, but nobody here knows it surely. Where I live +10% overvoltage is common. What will happen to your lamps is totally different story and as unknown without knowing some details.

Comment: Stick with 400 volts or even 450 volts due to coincidence of AC variations AND indirect lightning surges.

Comment: @brhans LED lights and i already did it, so i didnt specify what lights they are as i already know it will work, im just looking for cheaper ways to keep doing it. yes, they are brighter, but they also get a dimmer, so it ends up not really mattering

Comment: @user287001 current: well below their specification; ac current: none, these arent AC capacitors and they will not be exposed to AC. they are simply smoothing out DC. this is simply about AC overvoltage. if you say 10% overvoltage is somewhat common, then thats the answer im looking for, that means the capacitors are not safe for this application

Comment: "they are brighter, but they also get a dimmer" - sounds to me like they're now being over-driven -> overheating -> failing much, much sooner. But any LED lights intended to run directly from mains voltage which get brighter when you apply rectified & smoothed DC to them have got to be the real bottom-of-the-barrel nastiest LED lights on the market, without a constant-current driver circuit in them.

Comment: "These arent AC capacitors and they will not be exposed to AC. they are simply smoothing out DC." This is wrong. DC filtering capacitors are exposed to large amounts of AC **current**, not AC voltage. If they have to "smooth" a voltage, that means they have to supply the entire downstream circuit's current while the input voltage is in one of its "valleys". Possibly even more if a switching converter is involved (ripple current).

Comment: @brhans no, they arent "cheap bottom of the barrel", they are simply LEDs designed to tank 240v. these exist. these are incredibly common. if you buy a dimmable LED, thats the kind you get. if you dont buy a dimmable LED, its still usually the kind you get.

and yes they are overvoltaged, but they get a dimmer so i wont have to worry about this. in fact, this whole thing is so i can use a 500hz pwm signal to dim them rather than a triac dimmer

Comment: @JonathanS. yeah sorry, i misread that a little. english is not actually my first language

Comment: Then they're either very poorly designed or simply broken. Any even half-way decent LED light has driver electronics which already rectify and smooth the mains before applying that DC to a switch-mode constant-current driver which would operate at the very least in the 100's of kHz range. Pre-rectifying and smoothing the input to such a circuit, as you're doing, should have no effect whatsoever.

Comment: @brhans right, but then you cant dim the LED, so thats not used for dimmable LEDs. in fact, the only LEDs i own that use a driver circuit are the smart home bulbs in my room, and those actually use a constant voltage driver, not constant current. everyone is under the impression that LEDs always have a driver, but that is simply not true. any LED will either work at a lower voltage using an external driver or run at 240v and simply tank the voltage by having several dozen LEDs in series

Comment: Not true - the constant-current driver circuit in a ''decent' dimmable LED is able to detect the phase-cut dimming on the input mains and adjust its output appropriately. This is a more complicated circuit obviously, which explains why *dimmable LEDs are more expensive than non-dimmable ones*. If it were common practice to make dimmable LED using a simple nasty 'apply the mains almost directly to the LEDs' approach, then the cheapest LEDs would all be dimmable - which is clearly not the case.

Comment: Is this some DIY 240V dc panel lamp ? That would need  80 x 3V LEDs not several dozen. 325Vdc would need a lot more  ! What other specs do you have? I don’t find any common dimmable AC LEDs that flicker that require a cap to reduce ripple and raise Idc, unless it’s a DIY. What else are you not telling us?  The LED specs (?)

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 these are like 10 different LEDs, some of them made by osram, none of them DIY. they flicker at 50hz because thats mains frequency over here, which i can see because i am oversensitive to light, especially when using a phase cutoff dimmer. normal people do not need a capacitor to reduce flicker. i do. i cannot tell you the specs of these LEDs because i dont keep specs for every LED in my house. and 80 is more than 2 dozen, which is therefore considered "several dozen". and its not a 240v dc lamp, its 240v ac, which, if im not wrong, uses around 120 LEDs in series

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 and of course you dont find any LEDs that require a cap, most manufacturers dont list "will cause serious issues to photosensitive people if dimmed" as a bulletpoint on their LED. the only way to tell is to either get a photosensitive person in the room or to film it with a slow-motion camera.

Comment: If you are photo-sensitive, why aren’t you using 5kHz instead of 500 Hz which causes motion peripheral flicker for most people? Low dim light won’t increase 50 Hz ripple, if filtered to be low flicker, just the opposite. Is this a DIY?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 im using 500hz because thats the output of an arduino, and if that isnt enough ill look into increasing it. ive not had issues with 500hz before, but ive also never hooked up an entire room to a pwm circuit. and low dim light increases the amount of time that the light is off, which increases the dark period, which makes the flicker much more visible

Comment: 50 Hz or 500Hz  you are confusing 50 Hz flicker with 500 Hz low PWM and not defining your design very well.  FYI rectified grid voltage caps may need to be Y rated

Comment: What's the mains voltage tolerance in your country? 240VAC rectified leaves you with only 3% of tolerance, and typically you have at least 5% of tolerance in your electrical system. Not safe

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 the ac coming in that is problematic has 50hz. it is being rectified to have 0 hz. this is too bright, so it is getting dimmed using a 500hz pwm signal. other flavours of pwm are available, but this is the default frequency. i am not confusing anything here, but i am getting more and more confused by all this.

Comment: _"Mains in my country **is 240 V**, which means peak voltage of 339 V"_ - No, it's the _nominal_ mains voltage. In Europe it could be as high as 253V.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity#Standardization

Comment: @BruceAbbott thank you for joining us, yes that is what this post is literally about.

Comment: How not to make a reliable AC-DC offgrid without details. Good ruck with PLT’s without OVP trying to save a Buck!

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 this is entirely on-grid, i have absolutely no idea where you got this. you guys are way overcomplicating this entire thing, like have any of you ever done this? this hooking an AC light up to DC isnt rocket science

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for it.

I did the same some years ago when I used fluorescent tubes with rather substandard inverter circuits. I see 50Hz flicker, too (and it is 100Hz actually).

1. Most important: what can go wrong?

The capacitor will age faster. Since it is oversized in the first place, it will probably still outlive the other parts.

It may as well blow up. Will it make a disaster? Plus, sane capacitors have tops calibrated for pressure and they blow up as "pffff" instead of a "BANG".

2. These 350V electrolytics are made exactly for rectified mains for 220-240V markets.

In general, a cap is labeled for its intended use voltage and its surge tolerance is somewhere in the datasheet.

RTFDatasheet.

Comment: unfortunately the reseller doesnt list a datasheet, as the capacitors come from multiple manufacturers, though they do list MOST of the specs of the caps (but not its surge tolerance).

ill try to orders these for now, as they arent expensive. if they dont work for this project, im sure ill have another project in the future where i can use them.

thanks for the help

Comment: Apparently the OP is going for "cheap" rather than "sane".

Comment: @AndrewMorton im going for "delivery to my country" rather than "pay 50€ shipping for 5€ worth of components"

Comment: @Joshinken when the caps arrive, you may as well see the brand and model and look at the datasheet afterwards. Not the same as looking at before ordering, but still worth trying.

Comment: @Joshinken Ah, yes, delivery charges can be a real nuisance. Maybe there is some electronics club near you where they pool together orders to get round that.

Answer (score 0):

grid connected is called "off-grid" not "on" and grid stds vary in each country, 10% Vac tolerance typ or worse. There are standards to which choices are made. So it means you need excess storage energy to PWM the dips to null out the flicker. Then excess voltage margin too.  Have you ever monitored grid characteristics for quality? or compare with regional standards?  **Your low PWM flicker comes from the lack of current sensing  and regulating**

The Vdc rating / nominal grid tolerances affects the MTBF greatly by the margin ratio.  **This ratio is a historically-validated stress factor in MTBF calculations.**

Comment: ok we use different definitions of off-grid then, i take off-grid as meaning "not connected to the electrical grid". like people who live off in the woods somewhere and get all their power through solar.

And the vac tolerance is exactly what this question is about, so... youre treating this like i didnt consider that, thats literally what im asking about.

And there is no low pwm flicker. there is 50hz flicker because AC is an alternating current, and LEDs dont have the same afterglow as a tungsten filament.